# Check if url file exist until file exist

Tags: php

The code is working, but... How can I convert the "if" to a "while" so it will automatically refresh?. I'll be using the code to automatically check when a specific file is moved and then shows the download button.

```
$file = 'https://placeholder.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/placeholder-1.webp';
$file_headers = @get_headers($file);
if(!$file_headers || strpos($file_headers[0], '404')) {
    echo '<p>File not there</p>';
    $exists = false;
}
else {
    echo '<a class="button" href="' . $file . '" download target="_blank">' . DOWNLOAD . '</a></li>';
    $exists = true;
}
```

Comment: You should do that on client side (maybe Javascript) since a loop in your PHP file will probably not give you any answer (based on output buffering) until the file is available and in the end (if you not run into a timeout) give you 1000s of lines of "file not found".

Comment: Do you know for a fact that the file is there or will be there within a few seconds?

Comment: Yes, I know for a fact that the file will be there. I just need it to be an automatic loop so it shows "File not there" or "DOWNLOAD" once the file is there without the need of refreshing the page. I'm not really good with javascript, any help would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

This will loop until the file is found or the maximum time is reached and the browser will return an error.
Generally about 30 seconds.

```
$file = 'https://placeholder.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/placeholder-1.webp';
$file_headers = @get_headers($file);

while(!$file_headers || strpos($file_headers[0], '404')) {
    // code should remain here until above is not true
}

// then echo the download target
echo '<a class="button" href="' . $file . '" download target="_blank">' . DOWNLOAD . '</a></li>';
```

Comment: Thank you, I think now I understand how "while" works, but 30 seconds is not even close to what I'm looking for. Do you think what I'm trying to do is possible or should I start learning javascript to do it?

Comment: But you said: *Yes, I know for a fact that the file will be there.* So why isn't 30 seconds enough? If it's more than 30 seconds it's probably better to use a cron job to do x tries per day. Your question is unclear on what you actually need now.

Comment: I know the file will be there but not in only 30 seconds, there's a process before the file get there that can take from 4 seconds to 1000 seconds, that's why I'm trying to make a loop to catch the exact moment the file appear without refreshing the web page.